# Dynamically combine multiple reports using Sub-Reports - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm attempting to create a master report that I can use to combine multiple other reports into one. Ideally with the end result being a single PDF output.

I've been attempting to use a table to store the names of the reports I would like to populate into the master report and use those to define the SourceObject for the sub reports on load.

Ideally would like the option to have a variable number of sub-reports, so I've been attempting to use the Grouping function to accomplish that. So far the only result I'm getting is having the same report in all groups. I've tried putting the following code into `OnLoad` and `OnCurrent` - where txtPageReport is a textbox that is storing the report name.

```
subReportName = Me.txtPageReport
Me.subReport.SourceObject = subReportName
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way completely.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the recordsource query/table of report? How are subreports related to each other and master report? Please edit with details. I am almost sure you can combine all records somehow and simply use grouping.

Comment: The reports are all employee-related data for multiple clients of the company I work for. Each subreport would have a different category of data for each employee - basic information, compensation, etc. They would like the flexibility to rearrange these subreports or not include reports that aren't applicable for a particular company/employee.

Comment: Subreports like other controls can be made conditionally visible or not with [Visible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821493.aspx) property and have a `CanShrink` property that will not display if corresponding data is empty. Simply group main report on Employee and move all sub reports into grouping each linked by `EmployeeID`.

Comment: Yeah, however I'm trying to create one report per employee. Not a single report for a group of employees.

The idea was that I could create a list of reports for each employee - they would differ per employee. However when I try to group on my "EmployeeReports" table (which lists the reports for each employee) I don't get different reports in each sub report. I get the same report repeated multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two options which does not require table storage of subreports to be called dynamically by master report.

**Grouped Report**

Insert all subreports into the Group Header section (zero-length Detail section). Then, set each subreport Format property to `Can Shrink = Yes` and have report page break by Employee Group using `Force New Page = Before Section`. You can now open report in Print Preview and save as PDF using option on Ribbon.

[image: MS Access Report with Grouping]

**Non-Grouped Report**

Insert all subreports into Detail section (no grouping). Then, dynamically filter report using [DoCmd.OpenReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192676.aspx) method. Use `Where Condition` argument to filter by EmployeeID.

[image: MS Access Report without Grouping]

Below is a VBA loop to iterate through all employees and then [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192065.aspx) each individual employee report to PDF. Code can be used for either above grouped or non-grouped report.

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rst as Recordset
Dim strFile As String    

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT EmployeeID FROM Employees", dbOpenDynaset)

Do While Not rst.EOF
    ' OPEN FILTERED REPORT IN PRINT PREVIEW '
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , "EmployeeID = " & rst!EmployeeID

    ' OUTPUT REPORT INTO PDF '
    strFile = "C:\Path\To\Output\Folder\Employee_" & rst!EmployeeID & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "ReportName", acFormatPDF, strFile, False

    rst.MoveNext
Loop

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll give it a try and let you know if I have any follow up questions.

Comment: Quick question - what is the purpose of putting the subreports in the group header instead of the detail section in the first option?

Comment: Another question while I'm at it - I'm looking to have a page break between each sub report. Is there a way to adapt either of your suggestions above to accomplish that?

Comment: Group header or footer forces records to only those in specified group id, here being specific Employee. Had you put subreports in Detail - all Employees will appear which you had an issue about. See that in second type - Detail (no grouping) report. Hence you need the filter.

Comment: For page breaks, try spacing out subreports, resize their heights to never shrink, and keep checking adjustments in Print Preview. Or place couple in group header and group footer and specify [Force New Page](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Insert-a-page-break-control-in-an-Access-report-86d2ea7d-7aa6-44f2-8507-23134a9a2e15).